# Calculus of variations with double integral, inner integral's upper limit is outer variable of integration

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I want to find the function $\gamma(t)$ that makes the following stationary.

$S(t) = \int_0^t \gamma(t'') \Big(\beta\int_0^{t''}(1-\gamma(t'))dt' + e_0\Big) dt''$

Constraints:

$\beta\gt0$,

$e_0\ge0$,

$1\ge\gamma(t)\ge0$ for all $t$.

Can this be solved using the calculus of variations? I don't know how to deal with the inner integral.

Solutions obtained by numerical methods suggest that the $\gamma(t)$ that makes $S(t)$ stationary is a step function, transitioning from $0$ to $1$ at some point. If I *assume* it's a step function I get the solution

$
\gamma(t) = \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } t\lt \frac{t}{2}-\frac{e_0}{2\beta}, \\
  1, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$

Answer (score 0):

By Fubini's theorem:
$$
\int_0^t \int_0^{t''} \gamma(t'') \gamma(t') \, d t' \, d t''= \frac12 \int_0^t \int_0^t \gamma(t'') \gamma(t') \, d t' \, d t''.
$$
Maybe this helps?